# how to show set cell value in (-123) format with Open XML SDK?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an `excel file` opens it with `Open XML SDK` then looking for specified pattern in cells of all sheets when the pattern fiends, it replace with an value

```
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream(_excelTemplate))
        using (var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
            SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
            SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;

            foreach (WorksheetPart worksheetPart in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
            {
                Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

                var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>().ToList();
                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    foreach (Cell c in row.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        var cellAddress = $"{sheet.LocalName}-{c.CellReference.InnerText}";

                        var cellValue = string.Empty;

                        if ((c.DataType != null) && (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
                        {
                            int ssid = int.Parse(c.CellValue.Text);

                            cellValue = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;
                        }
                        else if (c.CellValue != null)
                        {
                            cellValue = c.CellValue.Text;
                        }

                        var cellFormula = _formulaParser.Parse(cellValue, true).ToList();

                        if (cellFormula.Any())
                        {
                            var formula = cellFormula.FirstOrDefault();
                            if (formula == null)
                                continue;

                            var cellKey = formula.GetCellKey();

                            var cellValueResult = _cellValueProvider.GetCellValue(cellKey, cellAddress);

                            if (cellValueResult.Type == null)
                                continue;

                            SetCellValue(c, cellValueResult);
                        }
                    }
                }

                sheet.Save(worksheetPart);
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }
            //doc.Save();

            doc.Close();

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            _result.Result = stream.ToArray();
    }

        private void SetCellValue(Cell c, (object Value, Domain.Entities.CellType? Type) cellValueResult)
    {
        c.CellValue.Text = cellValueResult.Value.ToString();
        
        if (cellValueResult.Type == Domain.Entities.CellType.Text)
            c.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.InlineString);
        else
            c.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
    }
```

I have two problem:

1- in line `var cellAddress = $"{sheet.LocalName}-{c.CellReference.InnerText}";` it will not returns user friendly sheet name.

2- after file saved and opens with `Microsoft Excel` value in that cell need to apply format by `Format cell`  in right click menu, it should be shown in `(-1234) format`.

How can I solve this problems?

Comment: The same way you do in Excel. You set the actual value `-123` and change the field's style to display negative numbers the way you want

Comment: I have no idea how to doing this @PanagiotisKanavos